# Image mask in Mozilla + foreignObject + Ajax

Tags: ajax, svg, mozilla, mask

http://continent-news.info/page_20.html 
In the left column of news, they opens in a popup window, and loaded with Ajax.

```
<div class="ukraine_mask1">
<svg height="116px" width="142px">
<defs>
<mask id="ukraine_mask1" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<image xlink:href="mask/ukraine_mask1.png" height="116px" width="142px">
</mask>
</defs>
<foreignObject class="recov_ukraine_mask1" style="mask: url(#ukraine_mask1);" height="100%" width="100%">
<div class="element_mask mask1_ukraine">
<img src="../inf_images/small/7812_8926.jpeg">
</div>
</foreignObject>
</svg>
</div>
```

problem in Mozilla:

Some news used map with a mask, the first time the mask works well. But if I click another news with mask, they does not want to re-use mask... =( If I press again the first news, it will work.
The second time,  does not want to re-use =(
If in firebug disable / apply 
`mask: url ("# ukraine_mask1")` 
in 
`foreignObject class = "recov_ukraine_mask1"`
it will work again ...
Maybe someone have an idea how to solve this problem?

I tried to add a simple style in СSS, but does not help = (

Comment: Could you create a minimal complete stand-alone testcase?

Comment: I have solved the problem by adding $('.recov_ukraine_mask1').css('mask',''); $('.recov_ukraine_mask1').css('mask', 'url(#ukraine_mask1)'); after complete loading Ajax..

Comment: That's nice but I'd like to fix it properly in Firefox if it's broken without making everyone jump through hoops.